# SwiftUI Resuming a navigation flow part way through

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationview

Is it possible to resume a navigation flow part way through after resuming the app? For example, if a user has registered an account, goes to validate their email but forgets and re opens the app later on, can we send them straight to the "Waiting for Validation" screens.

I get very strange behaviour when I attempt to set multiple navigation booleans to true on app start up to attempt to activate multiple `NavigationLinks`. The app occasionally opens on the desired page, but more often only on the second page in the flow.

Has anyone faced a similar problem in the past?

Comment: Have you tired implementing a 'Splash screen' that handles all the code you want running at the start of the app (and in your case run a bunch of if conditions to check if the user needs to validate their account) and send them to the relevant page simply by `if CONDITION { ValidationScreenView() } else { MainScreenView() }` You won't use navigation links in this way...

Comment: The issue with this would be that the user wouldn't be able to navigate back up the stack if they want to log in using another account, or register with a different email if they made a mistake.

Comment: Add a custom navigation bar with a button and use that button to take the user back to the relavent screen. So on your validation you can have a custom back button at the top and make it so it takes the user back to the previous view (You might have to use some UserDefaults to save information that they've inputted). I can provide you information with custom nav bars and such if you need?